# Can I use ST_Within or ST_Contains to update columns based on a geom being within another?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Based on the following tables:

Street

[image: Street]

Municipality

[image: Municipality]

I'd like to populate `Street.NOM_ENT` with `Municipality.NOM_ENT` and `Street.NOM_MUN` with `Municipality.NOMBRE` any time `Street.geom` is within `Municipality.geom`.

In other words, I have a table with all the streets in a country and I need to add to which state and county that street belongs.

I know how to check if `Street.geom` is within `Municipality.geom`, but I'm kind of new working with postgis/postgres and I'm not sure how to use this as a condition for an UPDATE query.

Comment: You _could_, easily, but it may not be what you want; any road that is not fully contained by (or within) would get no assignment, while, with `ST_Intersects` you'd get multiple assignments. I would use `ST_Intersects(municipality.geom, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(road.geom, 0.5))` to do this (assign the area where the midpoint is found within - a better assumption and a unique assignment); are these roads strictly simple *LineStrings* (as opposed to *MultiLineStrings*?

Comment: @geozelot I believe they are MultiLineStrings, not just LineStrings. Also, as far as the law around here says, it shouldn't be possible for a street/road to NOT be fully contained within a Municipality, meaning that it should be impossible for a road/street to be within more or less than 1 Municipality/State exactly.
Based on this facts, ST_DWithin works just fine to return the data i need, I'm just lost in the UPDATE part based on the ST_DWithin.

Answer (score 2):

If you are *absolutely certain* about the necessary restrictions of roads never crossing any areal boundary, use `ST_Contains` in the `UPDATE` like so

```
UPDATE <Street> AS s
  SET  "NOM_ENT" = m."NOM_ENT",
       "NOM_MUN" = m."NOMBRE"
FROM   <Municipalities> AS m
WHERE  ST_Contains(m.geom, s.geom)
;
```

Comment: Yes!, this works perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: @KurtPelzer very welcome. Consider *upvoting* my answer (ht the up arrow next to it) and, if it fully answers your question, to also *accept* it (hit the little tick next to it).

Comment: I Tried, but since this is my first question ever, I don´t have enough reputation yet. I'll come back to upvote as soon as I can.